# Simpler alternative to double if statement javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a simpler way to write this tiny bit of code:

```
if (a > max)
    a = max;
if (a < min)
    a = min;
```

What's the easiest way to do this in javascript?

Comment: Why is this not simple enough for you? Just make it a function.

Comment: Do you want to check both conditions one by one or check second condition if first one is false?

Comment: @Harry: but what if `max` is smaller than `min`? ;-)

Comment: @Joachim: That depends. If he want to check check second condition if first one is false than `max` must be greater than `min`. Or else `max` can be smaller than `min`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = (a > max) ? max : a;
a = (a < min) ? min : a;
```

or even

```
a = (a < min) ? min : (a > max) ? max : a;
```

Comment: I'll chose the the double `if` statement over this anytime! (re edit: that's a litte better ;) )

Comment: No its not easier to read, imho. And the original didn't work either. Maybe I shouldn't have bothered.

Comment: I find that parenthese, while redundant, make ternary operations much more legible: `a = (a > max) ? max : a`

Comment: If you're gonna combine it, `a = (a > max) ? max : ((a < min) ? min : a);` should be sufficient?

Comment: @Shawn Chin, that doesn't quite work as stated in question, when min is greater than max. Unlikely I know, and probably not quite what was wanted. But this is stackoverflow afterall

Comment: `a = (a < min) ? min : (a > max) ? max : a` should behave like the code provided in the question also when min is greater than max.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min):

```
a = Math.max(min, Math.min(max, a));
```

If you desire readability then something like this might be better:

```
function bounded(val, min, max) {
    if (val < min) {
        return min;
    } else if (val > max) {
        return max;
    } else {
        return val;
    }
}
```

This is very easy to understand and since it's only defined once the verbosity is not a major problem. Use it like this:

```
a = bounded(a, 0, 10);
```

Comment: I am not sure if that is better, though. Invokes functions (slower, two function calls even when the value is in the valid range anyway), and more difficult to read.

Comment: I agree. Just wanted to present an alternative.

Comment: thanks guys! thought maybe there was a shorthand notation for this maybe using the ternary operator. I'll stick to what I have then!

Comment: There is a ternary operator shorthand, see @NimChimpsky's answer.

Comment: @Lou Bandy: if shortness and/or readability is your concern, then you can write a function `bounded(val, min, max)` and always use that.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = Math.max(Math.min(a, max), min);
```

Is this really simpler?

Answer (score 0):

I think the code is a little hard to interpret for a couple of reasons:

- Single line `if`s split on two lines
- It is trying to limit a value in a range, but does not make it explicit.

Therefore I find the following indentation with a comment better, simpler and more clear:

```
// Limit a to the [min,max] interval
if (a > max) a = max;
if (a < min) a = min;
```

Bonus points: it makes it evident that we are assuming min<max.